# How to put self-signed certificate to each node of GKE cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes cluster in GKE. Inside the cluster there is an private docker registry service. A certificate for this service is generated inside a docker image by running:

```sh
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -sha256 -keyout /certs/tls.key -out /certs/tls.crt -subj "/CN=registry-proxy"
```

When any pod that uses an image from this private registry tries to pull the image I get an error:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Is there any way to put the self signed certificate to all GKE nodes in the cluster to resolve the problem?

UPDATE

I put the CA certificate to each GKE node as @ArmandoCuevas recommended in his comment, but it doesn't help, still getting the error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`. What could cause it? How docker images are pulled into pods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Almost all modifications you need to perform to nodes in GKE, like adding trusted root certificates to the server, can be done using Daemonsets.

There is an amazing guide that the user [Sam Stoelinga](https://github.com/samos123) created about how to perform what you are looking to do. The link can be found [here](https://github.com/samos123/gke-node-customizations#2-deploy-daemonset-to-insert-ca-on-gke-nodes).

As a summary, the way Sam propose how to perform this changes is by distributing the cert in each of the nodes by using a Daemonsets. Since the Daemonsets guarantees that there is 1 pod on each of the nodes always, the POD will be in charge of adding your certificate to the node so you can pull your images from the private registry.

Normally adding the node by your own will not work since if GKE needs to recreate the node you change will be lost. This approach of using DS guarantees that even if the node is recreated, since the Daemonset will schedule one of this "overhaul pod" in the node, you will always going to have the cert in place.

The steps that Sam proposed are very simple:

1. Create an image that with the commands needed to distribute the certificate. This step may be different if you are using Ubuntu nodes or COS nodes. If you are using COS nodes, the commands that your pod needs to run if you are using COS are perfectly outlined by SAM:

```
cp /myCA.pem /mnt/etc/ssl/certs
nsenter --target 1 --mount update-ca-certificates
nsenter --target 1 --mount systemctl restart docker
```

If you are running Ubuntu nodes, the commands are outlined in several posts in Ask Ubuntu like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate).

2. Move the image to a container registry that your nodes currently have access like [GCR](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry).
3. Deploy the DS using the image that adds the cert as privileged with the NET_ADMIN capability (needed to perform this operation) and mount host's "/etc" folder inside the POD. Sam added an example of doing this that may help, but you can use your own definition.
   If you face problems while trying to deploy a privileged pod, may worth taking a look to GKE documentation about [Using PodSecurityPolicies](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the solution is good, but somehow copying `myCA.pem` to /mnt/etc/ssl/certs and running `update-ca-certificates && systemctl restart docker` doesn't help. I've still got the error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

What I did you can find in a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67771013/how-to-generate-self-signed-certificate-for-ip-address-without-domain-name

Comment: probably putting the CA certificate to `/etc/ssl/certs` and running `update-ca-certificates` doesn't work properly. When I've tried to remove certificate from this directory and restart `update-ca-certificates` I got a message `0 added, 0 removed; done.`

Comment: I found another solution how to apply the CA certificate, but still continue to receive the error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: Hi Max. I was thinking that a possible solution is to use the svc name as CN for your certificate. If you create a [service in kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) you can create your self-signed certificate using the service fqdn as CN. For example, you can create a service "registry" in NS "docker" so the service fqdn should be something like `registry.docker.svc.cluster.local`. And you can use that FQDN for your CN

Comment: I found the problem. It was connected with `containerd` not `Docker`. You can checkout my answer here https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/14167/28062

Comment: Nick Stogner added containerd support to the solution talked about in this answer. Here is the commit that adds containerd support: https://github.com/samos123/gke-node-ca-importer/commit/756674ee595e1cf86df4b3181bb3cf687bd72c97